# R Project Folders Directories

Tags: repo

May I know, do I need to keep on creating a new folder directory and then initialize it every time I do a data analysis for every project? Such as I will initialize one folder. Then, I will create sub folders inside of that one particular folder for every projects i work with or should I keep creating new folder for every project and initialize it and then, commit it to the corresponding github repositories I have?

If I will be working on an existing directory which was initialized. Can I commit one or two files to different repositories in my github account like separating every file from one existing folder to be committed to different repositories in github? Is it possible?

I did some code of it. But, all of the files from the existing directory I am working uploaded or committed every files to one repository resulting to a messy repo. I have created different repositories from my github account to separate every projects and exercises.